# Javascript 2 decimals regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a regex that will match up to 2 decimals, so:

- 45
- 45.03
- 23.90

are a match

- -90
- jhjhjh
- 90.776

are not a match

Comment: it's funny you mention that. I did try it. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html. Using his validator, none of the answers found online work at all. i can't figure out whether it's the expressions that are wrong or his validator is wrong.

Comment: Well, what's the expression you tried?

Comment: I just tried the one given here as an answer /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/ entered it as is. Then put 90.88 as the value to test and it answered with no match. WTH?

Comment: I don't think the validator takes the `/` delimiters because they are not part of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[0-9]+|^[0-9]+.)([0-9]{0,2})
```

The above expression will match a number to 2 decimal places. I have tested this in PHP and TextWrangler.

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote in the comments and I used this one: `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The examples section in particular is something you should have a look at.